# JQuery Div Div id value (this)

Tags: jquery

I am using Simple Model (http://simplemodal.plasm.it/#examples) on a website i am designing and want to create pop up windows dynamically using AJAX.

The issue i have is getting the ID of the div that's inside the top div. I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="modal-ajax">
    <a href="#" id='test1:test2:test:3'>Link 1</a>
    <a href="#" id='test4:test5:test:6'>Link 2</a>
    <a href="#" id='test7:test8:test:9'>Link 3</a>
</div>
```

and jQuery:

```
window.addEvent("domready", function(e){
$("modal-ajax").addEvent("click", function(e){
    var values = this.id.split(':');
        var DisplayType = values[0];
        var ID = values[1];
        var three = values[2];

    e.stop();
    var SM = new SimpleModal({"btn_ok":"Confirm button", "width":600});
    SM.show({
        "model":"modal-ajax",
        "title":"Are you sure you want to delete this?",
        "param":{
        "url":"test.ajax.php",
        "onRequestComplete": function(){ }
        }
    });
})
```

});

so if i click link 1 i should get the value test1:test2:test:3 which i can then split on ":".

I need to do the above so i can send the split parts over AJAX to a php page that i can then draw a table from.

it seems no matter what i try i can not get the value test1:test2:test:3 when i click Link 1

Comment: well you are missing the `#` for the `modal-ajax` selector at the very least...

Comment: In addition to using `on()`, as akatakritos suggests, the jQuery way to do dom.ready is `$(document).ready(function() {})`, or simply `$(function() {})`.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you forgot the leading `#` in the selector.

But even if that where there. I'd be skeptical it would work because you bound your click event to the `div`, not the `a` tags. So when a link is clicked, the event bubbles up to the containing div. Inside your callback, `this` is bound to the `div`, not the `a`.

You probably want to do something like this:

```
$("#modal-ajax a").on("click", function(e) {
    alert(this.id); //see if this pops up what you expect

    // your code
});
```

This will bind click handlers to the links themselves.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution might be to use a data-* attribute(s) to make the code a little cleaner.

Example

```
<div id="modal-ajax">
    <a href="#" class="some-actionable-class" data-value1="test1" data-value2="test2">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="some-actionable-class" data-value1="test1" data-value2="test2">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="some-actionable-class" data-value1="test1" data-value2="test2">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
(function(){
    var getElementData = function(element) {
        return {
            value1: $(element).data('value1'),
            value2: $(element).data('value2')
        };
    }
    $('.some-actionable-class').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var data = getElementData(this);

        var SM = new SimpleModal({"btn_ok":"Confirm button", "width":600});
        SM.show({/* ... code removed .. */ });
    });

})();
```

Comment: I just start cringing when people add randomly-changing numbers and strange seperators to IDs...there ARE better ways of doing these things.